# Can I pass a comparison as a function parameters?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

My main question is, what type of data function parameters is accepting?
I would pass a comparison as parameters as for exemple

```
    Function test(a) //where A is a comparison so for example
test("a" == "a")
```

I'm trying  to get the comparison expression and not the result.

Is it something possible? Any way to do it? Thanks

Comment: This passes a boolean. What are you trying to do? If you want to pass a comparator, pass a function.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Sounds like an X-Y problem.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: In my function, people need to choose if they want compare an equality or difference or ... And I need to get the operator to execute the function. I hope it makes sense

Comment: Please post an example of how you'd call the function, and what it should do.

Comment: I'll edit my post

Comment: @BenM I've edited post. But I think the right question is : how I get the expression as a parameter and not the value?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass functions as parameters, and it's quite a common pattern in both JS and other languages to pass "predicate" functions.

```js
let isGreaterThan5 = v => v > 5;
let out = [1,3,5,7,9].filter(isGreaterThan5);
console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible:

```js
function isPosible(param) { // Here you define a function
  return param;
}

// Below you are executing the function and printing the result
console.log(isPosible("a === a")); // Returns the whole expression
```

More important is to understand that you can pass any expression as argument to a function, including but not limited to: **Any primitive type (string, number, boolean, undefined, null, etc..), functions (callbacks), expressions that evaluates something like your case**.

Comment: Do you need the whole expression? You can pass the whole value as a string `"a === a"`